# how would I get more reputation on this site?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I try to make good questions, but the next day I have less than the day before, even after I had 10 rep. and it went down to 2 rep.

Comment: well i tried to do my best on this question

Comment: For starters, it would help if you don't make a new account every time you log in to the site. I'm pretty sure I've seen your username on at least one Terraria question (about Duke Fishron if I remember correctly, which has since been deleted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are a couple things you can try to improve upon to better your reputation on this site:

**1. Your questions are often easily answered by quick searches, which are usually frowned upon for users to ask.**

For instance, take [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300185/how-can-i-find-the-cultists/300186#300186) you asked about Terraria.  Yes, I answered it, along with one other user, but this question was very simple to answer with a quick search.  You should try and look for answers first before posting a question.  Check the site and see if someone else has already asked the same question to avoid asking a duplicate.  I saw that from your profile you don't have internet access.  I'm not sure how that's possible if you are able to reach this website.  Bottom line is, try and answer your own question first before posting it here.

**2. Your questions often need to be revised.**

A lot of users will down vote questions/answers if they can't make sense of them grammatically.  I don't know whether or not English is your native language, which is fine if it isn't, but you must try your best to form grammatically correct posts.

**3. Avoid using this site as a forum.**

I believe in past posts made by you, (I cannot seem to find any so this may be false), there we more based around a forum-like site.  If I recall right, one of your comments on a post was essentially another question (which you could have asked)!  Arqade is a Q&A website (as are all the Stack Exchanges).  Posts are typically not open for discussion.  There is a reputation guard in place for new users to specifically help prevent this (not being allowed to comment on any post until at least 50 reputation).

These are just three things to keep in mind when using this website.  We have a lot of resources available for reference which you can find [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help).  You should start by [taking the tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) which will explain the basics of the site.

Some other good pages for you to look at include:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

Good luck, and welcome to Arqade!

Answer (score 9):

First things first - take our [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), or check out the [help center](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/help), for ideas of what's on topic and how we do things here, as it likely is different from other gaming related sites you've been on before.

Second, do your research! When you ask a question, try letting us know where you've looked for information or what you've tried - if the question is easily answered via a quick Google search, you're likely to get some downvotes for it, as the downvote tooltip reminds us that downvotes are generally to be used when "this question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful".

Third, answer some questions - you get more rep for good answers than questions. Check out our [tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags) to see if there are some unanswered questions for games you might know about, for example.

Fourth, be patient - this will take time. Continue to work hard at asking good quality questions and posting good quality answers. The rep will come - this community is good at rewarding people who put in the time. :)

Also, if you find yourself banned from asking questions (you will see a message that states "We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.") - this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) on Meta Stack Exchange (the meta site for the entire Stack Exchange network) explains what that means and what you can do to be able to ask questions again. It's not permanent, and it's not the end of the world (although I know it can feel that way.)

A note on rep - every upvote you get on a question is worth 5 rep, every answer upvote nets you 10 rep. Every downvote you receive (question or answer) subtracts 2 rep from your score.

Good luck, and welcome to Arqade!

Comment: To add to the reputation section, accepting an answer gets you +2.  When one of your answers is accepted, you get +15, and if you downvote someones answer, you lose -1 (however you won't be able to downvote until 125 reputation).  Approved edits also warrant +2, and you can also earn/lose a variable amount through [bounties](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).